# How to mock a static method in side a public class using Power mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, powermock

Hi every one I am trying to mock a static method name **mapCreditInfo(UCIPin, creditAssessmentResults)** which has two parameters **UCIPin** and **creditAssessmentResults**. UCIPin is String type and creditAssessmentResults is List 
This method is inside a public class ResponseMapper
type as shown below:

```
private CreditInfo getAccountByUCI(String audiUser, String UCIPin) throws EnterpriseCustomerVerificationException {
    List<CreditAssessmentResult> creditAssessmentResults = creditInfoRepository.getUCISummary(UCIPin, audiUser);
    return ResponseMapper.mapCreditInfo(UCIPin, creditAssessmentResults);
}
```

> Note: getAccountbyUCI method is called inside another public method
>   name **executeCustomerVerification** which is in the class
>   **EnterpriseCustomerVerificationService**

**ResponseMapper class**

```
public class ResponseMapper {

public static CreditInfo mapCreditInfo(String UCIPin, List<CreditAssessmentResult> creditAssessmentResults) {
    CreditInfo creditInfo = new CreditInfo();

    creditInfo.setUCIPin(UCIPin);

    List<AccountCreditInfo> accountCreditInfos = new ArrayList<AccountCreditInfo>();
    for (CreditAssessmentResult creditAssessmentResult : creditAssessmentResults) {
        AccountCreditInfo accountCreditInfo = new AccountCreditInfo();
        accountCreditInfo.setDelinquenctBalance(creditAssessmentResult.getPastDueAmount());
        accountCreditInfo.setNonPayDisconnect(creditAssessmentResult.getNonpayDiscount());
        accountCreditInfo.setPreviousAccountNumber(creditAssessmentResult.getAccountNumber());
        accountCreditInfo.setUnreturnedEquipmentFlag(creditAssessmentResult.getUnreturnedEquipment());

        accountCreditInfos.add(accountCreditInfo);
    }
    creditInfo.setAccountCreditInfo(accountCreditInfos);

    return creditInfo;
}
```

}

**I have Tried like some portion of my test class as shown below** :
Test Class

```
@PrepareForTest( EnterpriseCustomerVerificationService.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class EnterpriseCustomerVerificationServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
    private EnterpriseCustomerVerificationService enterpriseCustormerVerificationServiceMock ;
@Test
public void executeCustomerVerificationTest() throws Exception {
    List<ErrorResponse> errorResponses = getErrorResponse();
    List<String> mso = new ArrayList<String>();
    mso.add("a");
    mso.add("b");
    mso.add("c");
    AddressResponse addressResponse = getAddressResponse();
    String experianAuthorization = "experianAuthorization";
    String UCIPin = "110019";
    String auditUser = "ABC";

    CreditInfo credit  =   getCreditInfo();
    CreditCheck creditCheck = getcreditCheck();
    EnterpriseCustomerVerificationService spy = PowerMockito.spy(new EnterpriseCustomerVerificationService());

    PowerMockito.when(spy,PowerMockito.method(EnterpriseCustomerVerificationService.class,"executeCreditCheck",CreditCheck.class)).withArguments(Mockito.any()).thenReturn("@1");
    Mockito.when(creditInfoRepository.getUCISummary("110019", "test")).thenReturn(getCreditAssessmentResultList());

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(ResponseMapper.class);
    Mockito.when(ResponseMapper.mapCreditInfo(UCIPin, getCreditAssessmentResultList())).thenReturn(credit);

    CustomerVerification cv = spy
            .executeCustomerVerification(getCustomerVerificationRequest1(),
                    "101");
}
```

My question is how to mock **static mapCreditInfo** method using power Mockito ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far? You've written some test method which attempts to mock this static method so perhaps you could update the question to include that attempt?

Comment: ok wait @glitch

Comment: @glitch please check

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: @glitch Yes it is working fine when I create new test case  temporarily Thanks  :)   but giving null pointer exception when work that into my EnterpriseCustomerVerificationServiceTest.

Comment: Ok, so now you know "How to mock a static method in side a public class using Power mockito" perhaps the next step is to raise a question relating to this NPE, the more detail you provide the easier it will be to resolve. There are some [guidelines here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) describing how to create a question in such a way that anyone looking to answer it will have all the detail they need. As things stand anyone reading this question cannot resolve it because they have no details for this NPE and hence no way of diagnosing or explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this ...

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ResponseMapper.class})
public class ATest {

    @Test
    public void testMockingStatic() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ResponseMapper.class);

        // if you want to use specific argument matchers
        Mockito.when(ResponseMapper.mapCreditInfo(
            uciPin, creditAssessmentResults)
        ).thenReturn(creditInfo);

        // or if you want to match on any arguments passed into your static method ...
        Mockito.when(ResponseMapper.mapCreditInfo(
            ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), 
            ArgumentMatchers.anyList())
        ).thenReturn(creditInfo);

        // ...
    }
}
```

Notes:

- `@PrepareForTest` prepares the class with the static methods which you want to mock
- `PowerMockito.mockStatic` mocks all static methods that class
- You can use standard Mockito when/then constructs to tell the mocked static methods what to return
- The example above uses these dependencies:

  - `org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.19`
  - `org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.0`
  - `org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0`

**Update 1:** based on your updated question which shows your test method ...

My example includes: `@PrepareForTest({ResponseMapper.class})` your test method is **not** preparing `ResponseMapper` instead it is preparing `EnterpriseCustomerVerificationService`. It's like you are preparing the class which calls the class which has a static method rather than preparing the class which contains the static method.

I would strongly suggest creating a new test case - just temporarily - which looks like the one I have provided and use that to show yourself how to mock a static method and once you are comfortable with that then work that into your `EnterpriseCustomerVerificationServiceTest`.

Comment: I have already tried it but it gives the following error:  org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Comment: That message tells you that the argument you passed into `Mockito.when()` was **not** a mock. I'd suggest starting with the skeleton I have provided, it works.

Comment: Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.      what does it means ? @glitch

Comment: But the method in question here (`ResponseMapper.mapCreditInfo()`) is not final or private nor is it equals or hashCode. It's difficult to say what went wrong with your attempt since we cannot see your test code but the example in my answer works so I'd suggest that you start with it and either use it (and add you own test implementation to it) or you carefully compare it with what you have already written and spot the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to change the source code? if so maybe you could try to solve the problem without using any mocking framework at all.

see my comment on [How To Java Unit Test a Complex Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492468/how-to-java-unit-test-a-complex-class)